# How to state "Pat knows Mike's telephone number" in RDF/ OWL

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

How do I state Pat knows Mike's telephone number as a concept and not the concrete phone number 1112223333 in RDF/OWL?

Bonus points to be able to state Mary knows that Pat knows Mike's telephone number....

Comment: Your question is vague. In general, you have to create a property that has a person (or whatever class Mike and Pat are) as domain and range. Then just state this fact using a triple.  Is this a purely hypothetical situation? Or maybe you have an existing data set.

Comment: This is a purely hypothetical. Trying to understand at how you can reason about concepts vs concrete data in RDF/OWL

Comment: Basically, everything is a triple, consisting of a subject, predicate and object. In this case, Pat can be the subject, Mike the object and your predicate may be knowsTelephoneNumberOf. There are dozens of ways to describe it depending on the language you choose (RDF, RDF-S, OWL-Lite, OWL-DL, OWL-Full), each coming with different  potential when presented to a reasoner.

Comment: Ah thanks.  Didn't think of a predicate knowsTelephoneNumberOf. I guess the Telephone Number could be an object that has a property of the dialing number too.

Comment: This is just one way of doing it. Another way would be to use three triples. You could make the telephone number a resource of its own (not necessarily a literal) and then say that `Pat knows Number` and `Number belongsTo Mike`, where each part of a triple is actually a URL of a resource defined somewhere in your document.

Comment: This is a really general question. I'd start with reading the [RDF primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/) and then proceed to learn about the other languages. A neat comparison is made in a book I read, *"Semantic Web Services" J. Cardoso et. al*,specifically, in its first chapter, *The Syntactic and the Semantic Web*.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into that.  I was overwhelmed with all the choices in how to put together triples.

Comment: True. On top of that, you have different ways to actually write the triples. [RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/), [N3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation3), [TriX](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-56.html)

Comment: Sorry about posting over and over again but I grabbed the book I mentioned before from the shelf and I noticed there's an even better description of the languages in chapter V (Web Ontology Languages)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18690/discussion-between-carinmeier-and-tom)

Answer (score 4):

With a suitable property 'knows' you can use rdf reification:

```
:Pat :knows [ 
  rdf:subject :Mike ;
  rdf:predicate :telephoneNumber ;
  rdf:object <tel:1112223333> 
]
```

Few people like reification, but for this sort of thing it's ok. For the second case enjoy double reification:

```
:Mary :knows [
  rdf:subject :Pat ;
  rdf:predicate :knows ;
  rdf:object [
    rdf:subject _:b1 ;
    rdf:predicate rdf:subject ;
    rdf:object :Mike ;
    rdf:subject _:b2 ;
    rdf:predicate rdf:predicate ;
    ... sanity barrier exceeded ...
  ]
]
```

If you're happy to go outside a single graph life is simpler. You could just have a couple of files:

FILE1:

```
:Mary :knowsContentsOf <FILE2>
```

FILE2:

```
:Mike :telephoneNumber <tel:1112223333>
```

Or even stick both in a single file envelope and point to fragments of the file. This is essentially what named graphs give you in SPARQL.

Answer (score 3):

What about the following (using valid OWL DL for fun):

```
# assume prefixes defined
<>  a  owl:Ontology .
:Person  a  owl:Class .
:PhoneNumber  a  owl:Class .
:knowsThing  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :Person .
:belongsTo  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:range  :Person .
:Mike  a  :Person .
:Pat  a  :Person;
    :knowsThing  [
        a  :PhoneNumber;
        :belongsTo  :Mike
    ] .
```

Your other statement about Mary is more difficult because we are not just speaking of knowing a "thing", we are talking about knowledge about knowledge, which is very inconvenient to do in OWL and RDF. But let us stick to the challenge of doing it in OWL DL, with the following ontology:

```
<>  a  owl:Ontology .
:Person  a  owl:Class .
:PhoneNumber  a  owl:Class .
:knowsThing  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :Person .
:knownBy  a  owl:AnnotationProperty;
    rdfs:range  :Person .
:belongsTo  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:range  :Person .
:Mike  a  :Person .
:Pat  a  :Person;
    :knowsThing  _:mikesnumber .
_:mikesnumber  a  :PhoneNumber;
    :belongsTo  :Mike .
:Mary  a  :Person .
[]  a  owl:Annotation;
    owl:annotatedSource  :Pat;
    owl:annotatedProperty  :knowsThing;
    owl:annotatedTarget  _:mikenumber;
    :knownBy  :Mary .
```

The problem is that it won't get you much in terms of reasoning. user205512 and cygri's answers are plausible alternatives but they don't get you much either in terms of reasoning.

For more reasoning capabilities, you could do some crazy stuff like (only works with OWL 2 DL or OWL Full):

```
:subject  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :Statement .
:predicate  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :Statement .
:object  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :ObjectStatement .
:dataObject  a  owl:DatatypeProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :DataStatement .
:hasPhone  a  owl:DatatypeProperty .
:knowsFact  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain  :Person;
    rdfs:range  :Statement .
:ObjectStatement  a  owl:Class;
    rdfs:subClassOf  [
        owl:onProperty  :object;
        owl:cardinality 1
    ] .
:DataStatement  a  owl:Class;
    rdfs:subClassOf  [
        owl:onProperty  :dataObject;
        owl:cardinality 1
    ] .
:Statement  a  owl:Class;
    owl:unionOf  ( :ObjectStatement :DataStatement );
    rdfs:subClassOf  [
        owl:onProperty  :subject;
        owl:cardinality 1
    ], [
        owl:onProperty  :predicate;
        owl:cardinality 1
    ] .
:Person  a  owl:Class .
:Pat  :knowsFact  [
    :subject  :Mike;
    :predicate  :hasPhone
] .
:Mary  :knowsFact  [
    :subject  :Pat;
    :predicate  :knowsFact;
    :object  [
        :subject  :Mike;
        :predicate  :hasPhone
    ] .
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd solve this with named graphs. Stick the triple “Mike's telephone number is 1112223333” into one named graph, and than put another triple into the default graph that says, “Pat knows that named graph”.

OWL doesn't support named graphs, but SPARQL 1.0 and RDF 1.1 do, although there isn't a standard syntax yet, so you need to mess around with loading the various graphs individually into a SPARQL store from separate files.